# need to desc planned_at

Tags: laravel, model, controller, laravel-blade

**My Model:**

```php
protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'canceled_at',
        'checked_in_at',
        'planned_at' => 'desc',
    ];
```

**My View:**

```
@if(!isset($for_date))
   <td>
       {{ $reservation->planned_at->formatLocalized('%x') }}
   </td>
@endif
```

**My Controller:**

```php
if($request->filter == 'all'){
    $date = new Carbon($request->date);
    $this->data['reservations'] = $this->reservation_system->reservations;
}
```

I've added => 'desc' to the model, that's the only way what I can think of but then he gives me the error 'Call to a member function formatLocalized() on string'

Comment: Please clarify about what is it you expect . Do you want to sort by `planned_at` field or you want to fix this issue of parsing via `Carbon`?

Comment: I want to sort by planned_at

Comment: Alright, please show how you are populating `$this->reservation_system->reservations` property. Include your `controller's` code in question.

Comment: That's the problem. It is not in the controller. I don't know where to find it

Comment: Alright, let's assume this is a `web` route. So please paste your `routes/web.php` file here. This will reveal which controller is being served.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the queries sorted by 'planned_at' desc then you should use global scope. Find the documentation reference here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#global-scopes